# Setting content-encoding and content-type with Amazon API for .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3, http-headers

How can I set the S3 bucket file header to be the following:

> content-encoding: gzip
> content-type: text/css

I am using Amazon API using the SDK for .NET. I am uploading a file to S3 using the PutObjectRequest. The problem that when the file is uploaded, the content type and content encoding headers aren't beign updated (I've checked via the files properties on Amazon Console).

Example:

```
 request.AddHeader("expires", EXPIRES_DATE);
 request.AddHeader("content-encoding", "gzip");         
 request.ContentType = "text/css";
```

Also tried:

```
NameValueCollection metadata = new NameValueCollection();
metadata.Add("content-type", "text/css");
metadata.Add("content-encoding", "gzip");
request.WithMetaData(metadata);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you add the content-type to the contentType property in the api like the following

```
 PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
    string contentType = "text/css";
    request = request.WithContentType(contentType);
```

//for the content-encoding
//add the following header

```
request.AddHeader("content-encoding","gzip");
```

hope this could help

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer was right at the time but the API updated in 2014 so this is the new way

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    ContentType = "text/css",
    Key = filename
};
request.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. Current accepted answer is obsolete

Comment: If you are doing this with the cli, it looks like this: `aws s3 cp my_object s3://bucket/path/to/object --content-encoding gzip`

Answer (score 2):

In 2019 using the latest API the code will look like this:

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest {
    BucketName = bucketName,
    ContentType = "text/css",
    Key = filename
};
request.Headers.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
```